# The area between two curves - is my answer correct?

Tags: integration, area

> Find the area between a parabola $y=x^2-2$ and an asymptote to $y=\sqrt{x^2+4x}+2x $ for $x \to -\infty$. As an answer, write the area **multiplied by 6**.

This is a very easy problem, but I made some careless mistake at first and my answer was incorrect. However, the answer listed for this problem is just **1**.

First, we find the asymptote:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \sqrt{x^2+4x}+2x=|x|+2x=x$$

Then we find the intersection points:

$$x^2-2=x$$

$$x_1=-1,~~~~~x_2=2$$

Now the area is:

$$S=\int^{2}_{-1}(x-x^2+2)dx=2-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{8}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+4+2=4.5$$

Now the final answer is $6S=4.5 \cdot 6=27$

Where is my mistake? How could anyone get **1** as a 'correct' answer?

Comment: We have $\sqrt{x^2+4x}+2x\sim x-2+\frac{2}{x}+ O(\frac{1}{x^6})$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$. Thus I would say the asymptote is $y=x-2$

Comment: Ah, I see. So the points wiil be $0$ and $1$. That changes everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\sqrt{x^2+4x}+2x\sim x-2+\frac{2}{x}+ O(\frac{1}{x^2})$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$. Thus the asymptote is $y=x-2$. The points of intersection are the solutions of $x^2-2=x-2,$ i.e. $x=0\,$ and $x=1$. And therefore the answer is
$$ 6 \Big|\int_0^1  (x^2-2 - (x-2)) dx\Big|= 6 \Big|\int_0^1  (x^2- x) dx\Big| = 
6\Big|[\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^2}{2}]_0^1\Big|= 6\Big|-\frac{1}{2}\Big| = 1 $$